# jQuery: Selecting element after DOM injection (when element is unknown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

Is there a trick to inject arbitrary content into the DOM, and then select on that content, without knowing what the content is?

Example:

```
function myInjector( _htmlElement ) {
    $('#target').replaceWith(_htmlElement);
    /* Is it possible to then select the injected element here? */
}
```

I appreciate any advice provided.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to select it - you already have a reference to it stored in the `_htmlElement` variable:

```
function myInjector( _htmlElement ) {
    $('#target').replaceWith(_htmlElement);

    alert(_htmlElement.parentNode.tagName);
}
```

---

Edit — just create the new jQuery object first and store it in a variable:

```
function myInjector( _htmlElement ) {
    var newEl = $(_htmlElement);
    $('#target').replaceWith(newEl);

    alert(newEl.parent()[0].tagName);
}
```

Comment: Even if _htmlElement is only a string of content?

Comment: @Spot: Then you should not call the variable `_htmlElement` ;)

Comment: @Felix I don't care what the var is called. That is not the point of the question.

Comment: @Andy: Thanks for the update. Unfortunate this does not help me, as seen on the replaceWidth() doc page: "However, it must be noted that the original jQuery object is returned. This object refers to the element that has been removed from the DOM, not the new element that has replaced it."

Comment: @Andy: Accidental CR there. :) Anyway, I need the _new_ content, not the existing content. I can make the user pass a selector to find the new content. But before doing that I wanted to see if there was a way to do it in a cleaner manner.

Comment: @Andy: Perhaps I am ignorant to a function of replaceWith(). #target _exists_ on the page. I need to replace it with _htmlElement_ which does not exist. If my understanding of replaceWith() is correct, how can I replace on something which does not yet exist?

Comment: @Spot: nope, my mistake :-) I thought `replaceWith()` worked more like a swap - it would have made more sense to me. I've updated again - sorry about that.

Comment: @Andy: I must be doing something wrong. That exact code you have up there reports that tagName is invalid, and when I look at just newEl.parent() it's an empty array.

Comment: @Spot: here's a small example that appears to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/VhyXA/1 - maybe you can build on that?  Ha, ignore this then :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `_htmlElement` in `$`, making it a jQuery object.

```
function myInjector( _htmlElement ) {
    var element = $(_htmlElement);
    $('#target').replaceWith(_htmlElement);

    element.css('color', 'green');
}
```

Comment: Thanks but _htmlElement_ in this case, is a _string_ of html content (yes the var name is misleading).

Comment: @Spot That doesn't make a difference, at least my test suggests so.

Comment: Hmm, I wish I was getting the same results that you are. :) That would be what I need. Very weird. Is your test the exact code you have above? If so, what is the content of htmlElement?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myInjector(_htmlElement) {
var injected = $(_htmlElement);
$('#target').replaceWith(injected);
// injected is the reference :)
};
```

Comment: Thanks but htmlElement in this case, is a string of html content (yes the var name is misleading).